# Get Server Path of an Image by Product ID - Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, product-images

I have a CI project and a Magento Project on same server.

I want to periodically import Magento products into my CI website.

Everything is working perfectly, I am currently able to import each thing from Magento to my CI website.

BUT, ***how do I get physical/server paths of images of magento product?*** I want to copy those image files to my CI project.

Here is relative line I am loading product with

```
$product = $simpleProduct->getData()
```

And this is Image related part of what I get in return. look at `file` key, its not actual server path.

```
 "media_gallery":{  
     "images":[  
        {  
           "value_id":"6",
           "file":"\/2\/-\/2-2.jpg",
           "label":"",
           "position":"1",
           "disabled":"0",
           "label_default":null,
           "position_default":"1",
           "disabled_default":"0"
        },
        {  
           "value_id":"5",
           "file":"\/2\/_\/2.jpg",
           "label":"",
           "position":"2",
           "disabled":"0",
           "label_default":null,
           "position_default":"2",
           "disabled_default":"0"
        }
     ],
     "values":[  

     ]
  },
```

**PS**
I dont want browser path of an image like this http://www.website/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/-/image_name_here.jpg

I want server path.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no clean way of doing it out of the box.

The hacky script I tend to use is the following (note that `$file` corresponds to the data stored with the `file` key in your media gallery images array):

```
$imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $file)->__toString();
$imagePath = str_replace(array(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), '/'), array(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS, DS), $imageUrl);
```

Pretty sure I found it on StackExchange a while ago but can't get my hands on the link.

Comment: `    $_product = $simpleProduct->load($_GET['loadprod']);

    foreach ($simpleProduct->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
        $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($simpleProduct, 'image', $image)->__toString();
        echo $imagePath = str_replace(array(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), '/'), array(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS, DS), $imageUrl);
    }` returned me link like http://www.website.com/test/skin/frontend/default/kawaii/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg